# Hide the header row of Kendo-ui in angular

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I want to hide the header row of kendo-ui grid.  By this [answer on telerik forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-grid-with-angular---hide-header-row)
I applied the style.

```
.k-grid-header{
  display: none;
}
```

But the header is still showing. It means that the style is not applied.

Please see the [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jj57vb)

Comment: Please removed the hold. I updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add the `hideHeader` input to the kendo grid and set it to true

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="410"
[hideHeader]="true">
```

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-hideheader

Comment: Have you tried in StackBlitz? It doesn't work.

Comment: Have I tried what in StackBlitz? Your example or adding the ```hideHeader``` input? Because I'm sure my solution works.

Comment: Can confirm this works. Thanks a ton! I was banging my head trying to hide it via CSS in some nested grid. This made the job easy.